# How to process lambda statement to get data values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, lambda

Some background:

Here is my model for a membership user (extraneous stuff taken out):

```
public class Address {
    public String Address1 { get; set; }
    public String Address2 { get; set; }
    public String City     { get; set; }
    public String State    { get; set; }
    public String Zip      { get; set; }
}

public class MembershipUser {
    public String LoginId { get; set; }
    public String Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Mailing Address")]
    public Address MailingAddress { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Physical Address")]
    public Address PhysicalAddress { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

The Html helper method that I have written to output addresses:

@Html.Address(Model => Model.MailingAddress,  Model => Model.MailingAddress.Address1,  Model => Model.MailingAddress.Address2,  Model => Model.MailingAddress.City,  Model => Model.MailingAddress.State,  Model =>Model.MailingAddress.Zip)

@Html.Address(Model => Model.PhysicalAddress, Model => Model.PhysicalAddress.Address1, Model => Model.PhysicalAddress.Address2, Model => Model.PhysicalAddress.City, Model => Model.PhysicalAddress.State, Model =>Model.PhysicalAddress.Zip)

Surely there must be some way to call this like this:

@Html.Address(Model => Model.MailingAddress)

@Html.Address(Model => Model.PhysicalAddress)

I must confess that I have not had that "ah haa" moment with lambda expressions.   I can't seem to wrap my mind around them.   I have been searching the web, but I am not sure what I am looking for.   Any hints, pointers, nomenclature, examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you'd be better off defining an [Editor or Display template](http://www.dalsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2010/04/26/mvc-2-templates/) rather than Html helper extension where:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model)
```

Remember that for simplicity (ignoring Expression for now) the model => model bit and in particular the => is just shorthand for an anonymous delegate that allows your EditorFor implementation to callback and get the model object (in your case the Address) you want it to work with.

Expression gets a little more complicated but again in the simplest sense gives you the ability to package up the delegate and pass it around as "data".

Comment: Thanks Daz - I turned it into an editor template which seems to be working fine.  Thanks again for your help.